# "import tensorflow as tf" ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda

I am trying to learn Python and specifically TensorFlow. I have followed the instructions and have overcome several problems so far and have successfully installed TensorFlow (pip install), CUDA(9.1.85 win10), Python(3.6.3 amd64), and CUDNN(8.0 win10x64) as I have a GPU (GTX 1080) and want to be able to train networks with it. My computer has an intel i7, and Windows 10. I started with CUDA(8.0.61 win10) but it caused an error that said it needed version 9.

When I try to test with

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

I get this error on the first line

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

How can I fix this?

PS: I have read all other questions about this on this site and have also read the [common problems](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#common_installation_problems) page. I'm sorry the errors don't seem to match my specific problem but obviously I am lost here.

Comment: you've installed CUDA 9.1  You need to install and use CUDA 9.0 instead.  A concise set of instructions about how to fix is contained on the line that begins with `ImportError`.  Specifically: `install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit`  Since CUDA 9.1 is the current release, you can get the CUDA 9.0 toolkit from the legacy toolkits paged - linked from the above page.

Comment: The latest CUDA toolkit is always available at http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda   Older toolkits are linked from there on the legacy releases page.

Comment: Thank you it is downloading now i'll see it i can get it to import after installation. Unfortunately i don't have the greatest internet so I will check back in when i finish the steps you laid out thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow  does not currently support CUDA 9.1 see (may change soon though): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15656

You can download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Comment: Thanks! So i was under the impression that "Only works with 9" would mean 9.*.*** but i see that was incorrect good to know. I had been in the legacy section before so was not a problem but when I went there to download 9.0 it will only let me download 9.0.176. So am i understanding that it works with 9.0.*** or should i turn this around and look for a 9.0.000

Comment: Yes download 9.0.176 this will work with tensorflow. So ofcourse uninstall 9.1 before you install 9.0.176 and  everything should be dandy

Comment: Awesome! Thank you much unfortunately because i am so new my upvotes don't count but thanks just the same.